# tinyMCE with ExtJs, not defined error

Tags: javascript, extjs, tinymce

I'm trying to implement a tinyMCE editor into an ExtJs environment. But it's not going well.

First things first: Include the necessary scripts.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ext-2.3.0/adapter/jquery/ext-jquery-adapter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ext-2.3.0/ext-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/miframe-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Ext.ux.TinyMCE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(I have old versions of JQuery and Ext because I tried to copy the example/demo exactly).

Then I use some Javascript to define the window with tinyMCE in it, click on a button to initiate the popup window. When I try and see the result in firefox I get one error:

```
Error: tinymce is not defined
Source File: http://localhost:4927/ExtJS/js/Ext.ux.TinyMCE.js
Line: 301
```

Leading to this snippet:

```
/** ----------------------------------------------------------
    WindowManager
*/        
var WindowManager = Ext.extend( 

    function( editor ) {
        WindowManager.superclass.constructor.call( this, editor );
    },

    tinymce.WindowManager,  //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS

    {
        // more code
```

What am I doing wrong?
This is the base code I grabbed from the official TinyMCE ext page. So the js file must be okay, indicating I made a mistake elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yarr. Should include the actual plugin as well.

```
<script src="js/tiny_mce_src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Done.